# Find my iPhone keeps tracking me?

Tags: iphone, ios, privacy, find-my-iphone, geolocation

I have disabled Find my iPhone (under **Settings > My Account > Find My > Find my iPhone > Off**):

[image]

As suggested by bmike, I've also disabled tracking for the "Find my" app:

[image]

However, under **Settings > Privacy > Locations Services > System Services**, I can see that Find my iPhone (supposedly "off") is still trying to use the location services:

[image]

PS. I'm using iOS 15.5

Why is "Find my iPhone" still tracking my iPhone, even after I turned off "Find my iPhone"?

Comment: The Find My iPhone system may be reporting other device locations, but the solution regardless is to flip that last switch you're looking at to make your determination it's still tracking.

Answer (score 1):

The Find My app uses geolocation to show you where you are on a map so you can see other devices near by. Other devices can’t see this device - but if you want the map to show nothing, disable location services in settings.

Privacy > Location Services > Find My

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I've edited my question following your suggestion, as there is still a mystery.